# Compilation error numpy refactor (in ironpython) using visual studio

Tags: python, c++, numpy

long story here.

I am trying to get numPy to work with ironPython 2.7 (with Rhino3D). Everything is in x86, with Windows 7 enterprise, SP1. Visual Basic 13.00.

I found this, which sounds promising.
http://stevebaer.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/numpy-and-scipy-in-rhinopython/

Though the link http://www.enthought.com/repo/.iron/ is dead, and then I went to https://github.com/numpy/numpy-refactor/wiki/Recompile and followed its instruction.

So I downloaded numpy.refactor, and got everything working until ...
I got to step 4, which is to compile

cd numpy-refactor
ipy iron_setup.py

The VS compiler then errors out starting at line 246 of numpy-refactor/random/mtrand.cpp, and continues on (maxed out at 100) (this problem is not exclusive to mtrand.cpp but many other c++ codes)

```
static  CallSite< System::Func< CallSite^, CodeContext^, System::Object^, System::Object^ >^ >^ __site_call0_4297_19;
...
```

The errors are (this is from VS interface)

> Error 2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  C:\Program
> Files (x86)\IronPython
> 2.7\numpy-refactor-refactor\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.cpp    246 1   mtrand
>
> Error 3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
> does not support default-int  C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
> 2.7\numpy-refactor-refactor\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.cpp    246 1   mtrand
>
> Error 4   error C2059: syntax error : ',' C:\Program Files
> (x86)\IronPython
> 2.7\numpy-refactor-refactor\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.cpp    246 1   mtrand
>
> Error 5   error C2059: syntax error : '>' C:\Program Files
> (x86)\IronPython
> 2.7\numpy-refactor-refactor\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.cpp    246 1   mtrand
>
> Error 6   error C3224: 'System::Func' : no overloaded generic class
> takes '0' generic type arguments  C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
> 2.7\numpy-refactor-refactor\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.cpp    246 1   mtrand
>
> Error 7   error C2955: 'System::Func' : use of class generic requires
> generic argument list C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython
> 2.7\numpy-refactor-refactor\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.cpp    246 1   mtrand
>
> Error 8   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  C:\Program
> Files (x86)\IronPython
> 2.7\numpy-refactor-refactor\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.cpp    246 1   mtrand
>
> Error 9   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  C:\Program
> Files (x86)\IronPython
> 2.7\numpy-refactor-refactor\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.cpp    247 1   mtrand

I cannot find anything online that addresses this issue, or I missed some ... probably.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: The source is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-refactor/tree/refactor/numpy/random/mtrand) FYI